# splint large project (hundreds of files)

Tags: c, splint

I'm using [Splint](http://www.splint.org) for a moderately large project. All is fine, but we are now trying to up the level from "weak" to "checks". Because we are checking files one by one, Splint complains about undefined functions. I seem to remember Splint had the option to analyse multiple files individually and then do a final analysis of all together (compile + link style).

I can't find any info on how to do this in the manual nor general Googling.

Is this possible?

Comment: Similar to [this question earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525472/static-analysis-tool-silence-tool-on-external-functions)?

Comment: Thanks but no, Splint is a different tool from PC-lint, though they both do static checking for C programs. I have never used PC-lint (payware) but I'm guessing it's command line arguments and file's annotation will be entirely different to splint's.

Comment: I was referring to adding the proper *function prototypes*. Perhaps you are remembering wrong and that was the 'fix' - a static analyzer doesn't go as far as checking library paths.

Comment: there needs to be a header file for each source file.  each header file contains (amongst other things) the prototypes for the externally visible functions in the related source file.  Then any file that wants to call a specific function that is in another file, must include the header that contains the prototype for that function.